# jquery close container if anything except container and button is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have a button and group, when button is clicked group should show, when anything except group is clicked group should close. My code below is not working

```
<body>
    <div id="btn" class="control">
    <div id="group" class"control">
</body>

      $("#btn").click(function(){
        $("#group").toggle();
      });

$("body").click(function(evt){    
    if(!$(evt.target).is(".control")) {
        $("#group").hide();
    }
```

I can't put target as #group as this would cancel the toggle when button is clicked.

Using the code above the group shows when button is clicked but hides when anything on screen is clicked, including when button and group is clicked.

How can I get the jquery to work as expected?

Thanks

Comment: Check out my answer please.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code please:

```js
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  var target = $(e.target);
  if (target.is('#btn')) {
    $(".group").toggleClass('hide');
  } else if (target.is('#group')) {
    if ($(".group").hasClass('hide')) {
      $(".group").removeClass('hide');
    }
  } else {
    $(".group").addClass('hide');
  }
})
```

```css
#btn {
  width: 100px;
}

.group {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}

.group.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn" class="control">Click me</button>
<div id="group" class="group hide"></div>
```

Comment: I believe you are missing this `else if (target.is('#group')) {
      $(".group").show();
    }` since he demanded for #group to keep #group open

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, this will still hide the group when group is clicked, and not hide the group when the button is clicked

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Practice snippets, they can be tested on sight and get you greater chances of getting your answer chosen as correct or even upvoted

Comment: @nyx added as a snippet.

Comment: @TashaJordan this is your best option, it looks nice and clean and most important, it does what you required

Comment: @Nyx thanks, hope author will tick my answer as green)

Comment: @TashaJordan have you checked my last answer?

Comment: I couldn't get this to work on my environment as I had a form in container, I managed to get it working changing   "} else if (target.is('#group')) {"  to  "} else if (target.is('#group *')) {". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you good this is what you need? 
You can do this without class control, just with two ids. 
It will throw an error but that's exactly what we want. 
The code does as required. 
[jQuery.noop()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noop/)

```js
$("#group").click(function(){
 $("#group").noop();
});
$("#btn").click(function(){
 $("#group").toggle();
});
$("div").not("#btn").click(function(){    
   $("#group").css("display", "none")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div>EVERYTHING ELSE 
EVERYTHING ELSE </br>
EVERYTHING ELSE 
EVERYTHING ELSE </br>
EVERYTHING ELSE 
EVERYTHING ELSE</br>
EVERYTHING ELSE EVERYTHING ELSE
</div>
    <div id="btn">-----btn----</div>
    <div id="group"  style="display:none">-----group----</div>
 <div>
EVERYTHING ELSE
EVERYTHING ELSE</br>
EVERYTHING ELSE
EVERYTHING ELSE</br>
EVERYTHING ELSE EVERYTHING ELSE
 </div>   
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I accepted the answer above as I found it worked before seeing this answer. Also I am not sure what noop does